# Kubernetes cluster in Google (GKE) is over scaling nodes

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a Kubernetes cluster in GCP running with several node pools with auto-scaling enabled.
Seems like the auto-scaler is over scaling... 
Attached is the list of nodes and their usage (I'm using 32CPU machine type).

Can't understand why the auto-scaler doesn't merge some of these machines as the usage is far below the capacity and pods running on several machines can easily be merged into one.

I'm not using any special taints/affinities so I can't see why this over scaling is done. Reading the node auto-scaler documentation doesn't explain this type of behavior either.

Columns: status, requested CPU, Total CPU, requested RAM, Total RAM

[image: nodes list]

Comment: Certain types of POD can prevent cluster-autoscaler from removing a node. Check [this link](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#what-types-of-pods-can-prevent-ca-from-removing-a-node) to see whether your PODs are meeting those special criteria or not.

Comment: None of these criteria are met. Looks to me like a problem with fast-changing pods scaling. when upscaling, kubernetes dispatch new pods all over the cluster causing the nodes to stay up. maybe a way to prioritize new pods (from HPA) on the most loaded nodes?

Comment: In this [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/issues/2552) is discussed some reasons for cluster-autoscaler not scaling down the pods. According to our experience, some common reasons are Pods with restrictive PodDisruptionBudget and Kube-system pods that are running on the nodes that can prevent the autoscaler to remove a node.

In case you need further assistance, you can file a new issue to the [kuberentes community](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues) and post specific description of your nodes in there.

Comment: I'm not using PodDisruptionBudget and the only pods running in kube-system and GKE ones. I'm not using this ns. Is there a way to see the logs of the cluster-autoscaler under GKE (there is no system pod responsible for scaling)?

Answer (score 0):

As you confirmed about kube-system pods, you might have some kube-system pods running in the nodes that are preventing the autoscaler from removing the nodes; please see [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#user-content-what-types-of-pods-can-prevent-ca-from-removing-a-node).

Regarding the logs of the cluster-autoscaler under GKE, unfortunately I don't think you have such access. If you have access to the master machine, check Cluster Autoscaler logs in /var/log/cluster-autoscaler.log. Cluster Autoscaler logs a lot of useful information, including why it considers a pod unremovable or what was its scale-up plan. For more info, you can look at [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#ca-doesnt-work-but-it-used-to-work-yesterday-why).

Please note that it is entirely possible that the node is underutilized, but the pod would not fit anywhere else and so that can be the reason the node can't be removed. The logic is documented [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#how-does-scale-down-work).